# using windows startup script to copy files/folders from network share

Tags: windows, kerberos, cifs

I'm having an issue running xcopy as part of a startup script.

The server operating system is Windows 2008 R2 and the client operating system is Windows XP SP3.

File server hostname: filesrv1

DNS Alias (CNAME): filesrv

The command being executed through startup script is:

`xcopy /s/e/c/i/h/y "\\filesrv\lab$\JH117\documents and settings\default user" "c:\documents and settings\default user"`

If I change the server's name to filesrv1 then it works ok however not when using filesrv.  Once booted up and logged on I can map it and read/write/execute files using both names.

I made registry and serviceprincipal names changes as described in the following article but still having issues.  Any ideas?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308

Comment: is a computer startup script or user?

Comment: computer startup script.

Answer (score 1):

I added an entry for OptionalNames as well as DisableStrictNameChecking in the registry and that appears to have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a permissions issue? Unless you're allowing anonymous connections, you may have to allow the client machine account ($) permissions to read that directory from the file server.

Comment: No anonymous connections are allowed however Domain Computers are which is what allowed me to get this working when using the server's hostname.  I don't see how it would be permissions if I can connect fine from the same workstation when specifying the hostname in the script.  I am still not having luck with connecting using the CNAME.